# Oracle JDBC transaction management and committing sessions

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, session-state

Lets say i have the following bit of code

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;


    public class TestClass {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

            Connection database; 

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            database = 
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mydb", "user", "pass");

            if (database.getAutoCommit())
                database.setAutoCommit(false);

            String insertParent = "Insert into ParentTable (parentId,name,value) values(parentSeq.nextval,?,?)";
            String insertChild = "Insert into ChildTable (childId,parentId,value) values(childSeq.nextval,?,?)";


            PreparedStatement addParentStmt = null;
            PreparedStatement addChildStmt  = null;

            //Add the parent record
            addParentStmt = database.prepareStatement(insertParent);

            addParentStmt.setString(1,"Fruit"); 
            addParentStmt.setString(2,"Orange");

            addParentStmt.executeUpdate();

            //Now retrieve the id of the parent row to insert into the child row

            Statement stmt  = null;
            ResultSet rs    = null;

            stmt = database.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select parentId from parentTable where value='Orange'");

            //Now insert into the child table

            addChildStmt = database.prepareStatement(insertChild );

            if(rs.next()){
                addChildStmt.setInt(1,rs.getInt("parentId"));
            }

            addChildStmt.setString(2,"The Orange child");

            addChildStmt.executeUpdate(insertChild);

            addChildStmt.close();
            addParentStmt.close();

            database.commit();

        }

    }
```

Now every time i run the above i get the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

When i debug it, the exception is at the line addChildStmt.executeUpdate(insertChild);

I dont want to issue a commit after i have inserted the parent record. My understanding is that i dont have to commit if i am on the same session. Will the second insert statement shown above not be in the same session as the first one? Why exactly is the rs.next() not returning any value even though i had just inserted the record?

Thanks

### Edit

To compile the above code, The following tables will be required in oracle

```
create table ParentTable(parentId number, name varchar(20), value varchar(20));
create table childTable(childI number, parentid number, value varchar(20));
```

And two sequences parentSeq and childSeq will also be required in Oracle.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the real code. The code you posted doesn't compile

Comment: Hi, That code is just an example of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Since it's not real code, it's hard to tell where the exception comes from. For example, your insertChild query has three columns to insert, and 4 values inserted. You execute the update on addTransactionRecord, which is not even declared. All these could be bugs in your real code, but since we don't have it, we can't tell.

Comment: Sorry i have fixed the typos. The exception is happening during the addChildStmt.executeUpdate(insertChild). The reason for this is that if(rs.next()) is never returning true. 

All i am asking is why can i not read a row which i have not committed from within the same session. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not the real code, it's hard to tell where the bug is. But the strategy itself is wrong : if Orange is not a unique identifier, it can't work. You should

1. execute a select statement to get the next value from the parent sequence and get a parent ID
2. execute an insert statement to insert a parent with this parent ID
3. execute a select statement to get the next value from the child sequence and get a child ID
4. execute an insert statement to insert a child with the parent and child IDs.

EDITED :

Now that the code is OK, I have found the bug. Replace

```
addChildStmt.executeUpdate(insertChild);
```

with

```
addChildStmt.executeUpdate();
```

(and fix the name of the childId column). A debugger or a simple log would have shown that the select query does return the parent ID.

Comment: Hi this is what i am trying to do but i am getting the id's by reading the parent row. Assuming that Orange is unique how would i read the row i just inserted. The problem i have having is i cant read a row i have just inserted without having to commit first.

Comment: You should be able to read what you just inserted without committing. There is probably a bug in your code, but you don't want to show it.

Comment: Hi sorry its not that i dont want to show it. The queries are generated dynamically so it is practically impossible to show it without posting several source files and the content of some tables which contain the query strings. This is the reason i tried to show the example above.  

So if i issue one insert statement i should be able to read the record i just inserted without commiting? Does it make any difference if a different PreparedStatement is used?

Comment: It makes a difference if it's not the same connection. It's not a problem if it's not the real code. But it should be code that compiles, that you've tried running, and that's exhibiting the problem. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ok i have edited it with an updated version which compiles fine and fails at the addChildStmt.executeUpdate(insertChild) line.

Comment: Thanks yes i did edit the column name. Im suprised that the compiler did not complain about that line. I just looked at the API and there is no executeUpdate that takes a string as a parameter. I dont know why the compiler did not show a compiler error.

Comment: There is one : it's inherited from Statement.